# When to index, what to index in Mongoid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, indexing

I'm a bit new to indexes, but I am curious about the usecases for an index. (I assume it makes queries on the indexed fields much faster.) Is there a criteria for determining what to index and when to index? What kind of performance benefits should I expect -- specifically using Mongoid with MongoDb on a Rails app?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check out [Indexes](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexes) MongoDB docs and [Indexing Advice and FAQ](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexing+Advice+and+FAQ), lots of great info here.

Comment: Yea a little too much info though. I get overwhelemed everytime.