# Rails 4 and Mongo DB 4.x error when iterating over the "big" collection

Tags: ruby, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid, mongodb-query

Having Mongo backed model with about 800-900 records I'm trying to iterate over and generate CSV using some of the attributes.

So it's look like this:

```
each do |car|
  csv << columns.map { |column| car.__send__(column) }
end
```

And I'm getting error like this:

```
A Moped::Errors::QueryFailure occurred in cars#index:

  The operation: #<Moped::Protocol::Query
  @length=94
  @request_id=376
  @response_to=0
  @op_code=2004
  @flags=[]
  @full_collection_name="app555555.cars"
  @skip=0
  @limit=0
  @selector={"$query"=>{}, "$orderby"=>{"created_at"=>-1}}
  @fields=nil>
failed with error 10128: "too much data for sort() with no index.  add an index or specify a smaller limit"

See https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/docs/errors.md
for details about this error.
  app/models/car.rb:84:in `block in to_csv'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably missing index. Here's more about adding indexes in mongo DB [When to index, what to index in Mongoid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6183945/when-to-index-what-to-index-in-mongoid) and http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/ruby-mongoid-tutorial/#id12

Comment: Thanks grimsock, I have added index on the default order column (it was `created_at`) and it works!